# How to write IN clause in hibernate native(createNative) query?

Tags: sql, hibernate, native

How to complete this query with IN clause?

```
ArrayList<Long> statusIds = new ArrayList<Long>();
        _merchantTransaction.getMerchantTxnStatusList().forEach(statusItem ->{
            statusIds.add(statusItem.getMerchantTxnStatusId());
        });
        Query query =  entityManager.createNativeQuery("select *"
                + " from merchant_transactions mt" 
                + " inner join appl_merchant_txn_statuses mts on mt.merchant_txn_status_id = mts.merchant_txn_status_id"
                + " where"
                  + " mt.customer_id ="+ _merchantTransaction.getCustomerId()
                  + " and mt.merchant_transaction_type_id = "+ _merchantTransaction.getMerchantTransactionType().getMerchantTransactionTypeId()
                  + " and mt.merchant_txn_status_id in " + statusIds
                  ,MerchantTransaction.class);
```

While executing, this result following query and it gives

> SQLGrammerExecption.

```
select * 
from merchant_transactions mt where 
mt.customer_id = 3998 
and mt.merchant_transaction_type_id = 2 
and mt.merchant_txn_status_id in [1, 8]);
```

How to solve this?

Thanks & Regards,
Dasun.

Comment: Can you paste the whole stacktrace?

Comment: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider using **named parameter bindings** instead of adding the parameters directly by concatenation as follows:

```
Query query =  
    entityManager.createNativeQuery("select *"
        + " from merchant_transactions mt" 
        + " inner join appl_merchant_txn_statuses mts on mt.merchant_txn_status_id = mts.merchant_txn_status_id"
        + " where mt.customer_id = :customer_id"
        + " and mt.merchant_transaction_type_id = :merchant_transaction_type_id"
        + " and mt.merchant_txn_status_id in (:status_ids)", MerchantTransaction.class);

query.setParameter("customer_id", _merchantTransaction.getCustomerId());
query.setParameter("merchant_transaction_type_id", _merchantTransaction.getMerchantTransactionType().getMerchantTransactionTypeId());
query.setParameter("status_ids", statusIds);
```

Advantages of named parameter bindings as described in hibernate best-practices [here](https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-best-practices/):

- you do not need to worry about SQL injection,
- Hibernate maps your query parameters to the correct types and
- Hibernate can do internal optimizations to provide better
  performance.

As a side note, I see that you are using JPA's Entity Manager createNativeQuery, so this will work:
`query.setParameter("status_ids", statusIds);`

If you were using Hibernate createSQLQuery, you need this:

> query.setParameterList("status_ids", statusIds);